# JSON/LIST. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, json

He creado una función para leer un json y sacar sus datos:

```
def leerJSON(carrito):
    text = carrito.text #(Línea 7)
    data = json.loads(text)
    
    lista_nombres_y_usuarios = []
    for i in range(10):
        data = json.loads(text)
        user = data[i]
        nombre = user['name'] 
        username = user['username']
        email = user['email']
        #address = user['address']['zipcode']
        lista_nombres_y_usuarios.append([nombre, username])

    splits = np.array_split(lista_nombres_y_usuarios, 10)
    for array in splits:
        print("Splited:" , array, "\n")

    return(nombre, username, email, array)
```

Esta es la función creada. Cuando la llamo desde otro script y le paso el json como parámetro de la función para que me devuelva los datos que quiero leer me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Escritorio/Factura/prueba.py", line 15, in <module>
    [name, username, email, array] = leerJSON(c)
  File "/home/Escritorio/Factura/funcionLecturaJSON.py", line 7, in leerJSON
    text = carrito.text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Me sale que la variable carritojson que yo creo no tiene el atributo text, y no se porque pasa eso.

Este es el script desde el que llamo a la función de leerJSON():

```
    #prueba.py
carritojson = {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Leanne Graham",
        "username": "Bret",
        "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
        "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
        "website": "hildegard.org",
    }
    
    
    [name, username, email, array] = leerJSON(carritojson)
    print(name)
    print(username)
    print(email)
    print(array)
```

EDITADO: A la salida si hay mas de un registro quedaría algo asi (en este caso está con 5 registros):

```
[['Leanne Graham', 'Bret'], ['Ervin Howell', 'Antonette'], ['Clementine Bauch', 'Samantha'], ['Gervas Howell', 'Anton'], ['David Bauch', 'Sam']]
```

Comment: ¿Probaste la misma función con el mismo `carritojson` en el archivo de la función? Parece ser que el problema es el tipo de objeto que estás intentando utilizar, es decir, `carritojson` en tu ejemplo es un diccionario, no un `JSON`.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato y como puedo hacer que carritijson pase de ser un diccionario a un JSON? Si, teniendo el archivo en el mismo archivo de la función va bien.

Comment: Hola David. Veo varios errores en tu código. Primero, como apunta @HeytalePazguato, **carritojson** es un objeto y el método **loads** espera un string, así que deberás pasarla como string, por ejemplo, pon tres comillas simples antes de la llave de apertura y otras tres antes de la de cierre. Por otro lado, te sobra la coma en **"hildegard.org",** ya que un JSON no puede acabar así. Ahora puedes cambiar **carrito.text** por **carrito** ya que ahora **carrito** ya es un string. Sigue otro comentario.

Comment: Pero lo peor es que no entiendo tu código, ¿por qué haces **data = json.loads(text)** en la línea 2 de la función, si luego lo vuelves a hacer en la línea 6? y ¿para qué es el bucle for? ¿por qué 10?. No sé si es que esperas que tu json tenga más de un registro.

Comment: Hola @PedroGonzález, gracais por la respuesta. data = json.loads(text) está dos veces puesto porque estaba realizando pruebas de donde va mejor. El bucle for es porque el json dentro tiene distintos registros y de esta forma puedo leer todos de unos en uno según su id (data[i]).

Comment: Es lo que suponía. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que debería mostrase en la salida cuando hay al menos dos registros en la entrada? Es que con tu ejemplo no entiendo qué es lo que esperas a la salida.

Comment: @PedroGonzález he editado la pregunta y he añadido al final como tendría que ser la salida. Ese sería el array, los otros valores serían individualmente cada uno de los parámetros del json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es que no entendía qué querías sacar con las variables name, username, email y array.

Si lo único que pretendes es hacer eso, el código se puede simplificar mucho, algo así

```
import json

def leerJSON(carrito):
    data = json.loads(carrito)
    
    lista_nombres_y_usuarios = []
    for user in data:
        lista_nombres_y_usuarios.append([user['name'], user['username']])

    return lista_nombres_y_usuarios


carritojson = '''[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org"
},{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Graham Leanne",
    "username": "Sam",
    "email": "samgl@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-780-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org"
},{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Graham Kendell",
    "username": "Olivia",
    "email": "ogk@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-790-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org"
}
]'''


lista = leerJSON(carritojson)
print(lista)
```

Como ves, a la función le paso el json como un string (que tiene forma de array) y una vez parseado recorro la lista, extrayendo el **name** y **username** y metiéndolo como una tupla en un nuevo vector, que es el que devuelvo.

Observa también que el for no es de 10 elementos, lo cual daría multitud de problemas. Por el contrario, hago un for sólo del número de elementos que tiene el vector. Así funcionará independientemente del número de elementos de la lista.

Espero que te valga así.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
from jsonwhatever import jsonwhatever as jw

carritojson = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org"
},{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Graham Leanne",
    "username": "Sam",
    "email": "samgl@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-780-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org"
},{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Graham Kendell",
    "username": "Olivia",
    "email": "ogk@april.biz",
    "phone": "1-790-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org"
}
]

print(jw.jsonwhatever('carritojson',carritojson))
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.